# BroadcastReceiver not always fired up with AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Some days were spent to find the answer here but nothing.

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private myReceiver rec;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        rec = new myReceiver(); // do I really need this?
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, myReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5 , pi);
    }
}
```

xml

```
<application ...>
...
<receiver android:name="com.myprj.myReceiver" android:enabled="true"></receiver>
</application>
```

It works not always but when "it wants" :(

NOTE!: I started to press Ctrl+F11 in Eclipse and close app with back button and again Ctrl-F11! SO, on 7-th iteration, application worked (toast in onReceive). I stopped it, delete data and start pressing Ctrl-F11 again, on the 3-rd iteraton - worked, and 5-th iteration is also working... What is it?

Comment: `It works not always but when "it wants" :(` !Its not digestible please provide accurate info.

Comment: I added toast to onReceive, update app on my device and it started to work. Ok. Then I remove my app from the phone and reinstall it again w/o any code changes, and nothing worked... I confused. I'm using in AVD my real device.

Comment: what to update? and fresh installing is not working, is it?

Comment: After adding Toast to onReceive I made Ctrl+F11 and updated copy of my application was landed to the phone. Fresh install doesn't work.

Comment: go through this [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) or keep debug point and trace.

Comment: New debug way. I started to press Ctrl+F11 in Eclipse and close app with back button and again Ctrl-F11! SO, on 7-th iteration, application worked (toast in onReceive). I stopped it, delete data and start pressing Ctrl-F11 again, on the 3-rd iteraton - worked, and 5-th iteration is also working... What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Few changes you may try (not all are necessary)

1. Change myReceiver to MyReceiver ( :-) its a Java naming convention)
2. Remove

   `rec = new myReceiver();`
3. Give some future time instead of current time in millis

   `am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 5, 1000 * 5 , pi);`
4. Put a debug message in onReceive()

   `Log.d("MyReceiver", "onReceive");`